# Getting syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting {

Tags: go

I was trying for, break and continue in golang and I did this...

```
func main() {
    for k, i := 0, 0; i < 10; i++, k++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            if k == 10 {
                fmt.Println("Value of k is:", k)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this syntax error on line of the 1st `for`:

> syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting {

I don't know, how the correct syntax should be instead.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/wL8rL9fepd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to initialize both `k` and `i`: `for k, i := 0, 0;`

Additionally you can't do: `i++, k++`. Instead you have to do  `i, k = i+1, k+1`

See [this reference in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for):

> Finally, Go has no comma operator and ++ and -- are statements not
>   expressions. Thus if you want to run multiple variables in a for you
>   should use parallel assignment (although that precludes ++ and --).
>
> // Reverse a
>
> `for i, j := 0, len(a)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
>       a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }`

```
func main() {
    for k, i := 0, 0; i < 10;  i, k = i+1, k+1 {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            if k == 10 {
                fmt.Println("Value of k is:", k)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that `k` never reaches 10 like this, so your message won't print. You are incrementing `i` & `k` at the same time and the outer loop stops at `i < 10` (and thus `k < 10`).

Comment: Ya, I know, i was just playing with for, break and continue. Thanks for the answer...